# How to get all containers using Dockerode and Javascript

Tags: javascript, meteor, docker, containers

I'm trying to display on a Meteor app all running containers and all stopped containers that I have in Docker. For the moment I can only display the running containers when I stop one he's deleted from the DB automatically.

There is my code where I get the containers (and where I need a little bit help to got the stopped containers too):

```
    infosContainers.initContainers': function() {
    /* create Docker object */
    docker = new Docker({socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'});
    /* create 2 var that are my containers running in docker */
    meteorCtn = docker.getContainer('vialfeedmaclecturearticle_app_1');
    mongoCtn = docker.getContainer('vialfeedmaclecturearticle_mongo_1');
    /* I don't really understand but it's on the Dockerode page */
    meteorCtn.defaultOptions.start.Binds = ["/tmp:/tmp:rw"];
    mongoCtn.defaultOptions.start.Binds = ["/tmp:/tmp:rw"];

    /* Add the id in the collection */
    docker.listContainers(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (err, containers) {
      containers.forEach(function (containerInfo) {
        InfosContainers.insert({
          idContainer: containerInfo.Id,
          nameContainer: containerInfo.Names[0],
          stateContainer: containerInfo.State
        });
      });
    }));
  },
```

Someone has already done that ? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always when you ask you find... so there is the solution

```
   docker.listContainers({all: true}, function(err, containers) {
   console.log('ALL: ' + containers.length);
   });
```